# Is there an R package to estimate the order of a Markov Process?

Tags: r, markov-chains

The following link:

[RTransferEntropy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTransferEntropy/vignettes/transfer-entropy.html)

describes how measure the information transfer between different time series. The code requires an estimation of the order of the Markov Processes corresponding to both discrete random variables.

Do you know any R packages able to perform this task?

Comment: Do you mean the `lx`, `ly` arguments? (author of the package here)

Comment: Yes! I meant them

Comment: They refer to the lags. That is, if you want to get the effects of a lag of 1, you set `lx = 1` etc.

Comment: Thank you! Then I could estimate `lx` by `timeLag` function contained in `nonlinearTseries` package? E.g. by selecting the time lag where the autocorrelation/AMI function decays to 0 (first.zero selection
method)?

Comment: Certainly, that would be a way to go about it!

Comment: @David thank you for your answer. I estimated the delays as 32 and 3. Anyway, according to this, the function `calc_ete(series1, series2, lx=32, ly=3)` returns: `Error in calc_te_ete("ete", x, y, lx = lx, ly = ly, entropy = entropy,  :Markov order/number of lags should not exceed 20. Do not expect sensical results when using too many classes and/or lags.`. If I set `lx=20` (e.g.) instead of 32 I obtain 0 as a result and the warning message: `Markov order/number of lags should be identical for both time series to facilitate interpretation of results. Consider setting lx = ly.` Why?